# how to return specific set of data from from array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following data contract available in constant variable `data`

```
[
{
  id: 1,
  name: "class1",
  start_at: "2017-08-15T10:00:00.000Z",
  end_at: "2017-08-15T10:30:00.000Z",
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "class2",
  start_at: "2017-08-15T10:00:00.000Z",
  end_at: "2017-08-15T10:30:00.000Z",
 },
 ......more data here.....
]
```

I want to return the specific set of data.
e.g `data.select {|e| e[:id] = 1}` should return following but instead it returns all data.

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "class1",
  start_at: "2017-08-15T10:00:00.000Z",
  end_at: "2017-08-15T10:30:00.000Z",
 }
]
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: use `==` for comparison, you are using `=`

Comment: I have three general suggestions concerning the use of examples in questions. Firstly, make the example complete so that all inputs are valid Ruby objects.  For example, no "......more data here.....". The reason is that you want to allow readers to run code that produces the desired result for your example. Secondly, you want to always give the desired result for you example. You've done that. Thirdly, assign variables to all input objects so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. Here you might write `arr = [ { id: 1,...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extracted_data = data.select {|e| e[:id] == 1}`

`==` for comparison

Comment: is this JSON? if it is `data.select {|e| e['id'] == 1}`

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/AstonishingNauticalBufflehead returns as expected